# trying to get fullscreen window with PyGTK on Ubuntu Natty

Tags: pygtk, fullscreen, ubuntu-11.04

I have been looking around but was unable to find and answer to the following question:

I am using PyGTK and PyGTKGLEXT to write an application that should have a fullscreen window with OpenGL capabilities. 
I am on Ubuntu Natty with the Unity desktop, and if I ask my window to go fullscreen, the Natty menubar that is always there at the top of the screen does not go away.
This ruins my fullscreen experience, but I am unable to find an approach to get rid of it (and restore it after my window quits). I do hope that is possible !

All pointers are very welcome !

Joost.

Answer (score 0):

The version doesn't tell me whether your using Unity or Gnome. However, if you're using Gnome, [THIS](http://infinity-unbound.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-make-your-window-full-screen-in_15.html) may be helpful. It may be a similar method with Unity.

However, I do not think this can be programmed in - the user must make the setting change.